# Best sequence using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have ordered list like in example

```
var someList = new List<int>{1,1,2,3,5,2,1,3,7,1};
```

I want to select by using LINQ best(highest sum) sequence of 3 numbers. 
In this case answer is 3,7,1 or 1,3,7. Is that possible without change order or sorting?
I have an idea how to do this without LINQ, but I just wanna know to do with LINQ

Comment: This list in unordered.

Comment: Why would you try to get a top 3 without ordering?

Comment: I think the point is that it's in some other order - e.g. orders per day - and the aim is to find the highest "3 day total".

Comment: I'm believe this should definitely need a for loop. LINQ seems the hardest way.

Comment: I'm guessing it needs to be in this order, and then the algorithm is sum of 1,1,2, then sum of 1,2,3 etc...then, select the greatest value from the sequence?

Comment: I'm not sure this would be better *with* LINQ than *without* it.

Comment: *sigh* why does every sequence problem have to be solved with Linq..? It's still ok to write a for loop!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use Skip/Zip to end up with triples. For example:

```
var triples = list.Zip(list.Skip(1).Zip(list.Skip(2), (b, c) => new { b, c }),
                       (a, bc) => new { a, bc.b, bc.c });
```

(That may have some errors - I haven't tested it yet.)

You can then order those triples pretty easily:

```
var orderedTriples = triples.OrderByDescending(t => t.a + t.b + t.c);
```

If you're using the triples in multiple contexts, you might want to write an extension method to use `Tuple<,,>` instead:

```
public static IEnumerable<Tuple<T, T, T>> InTriples<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    // Or potentially write custom code to do this. It wouldn't be too hard...
    return source.Zip(list.Skip(1).Zip(list.Skip(2), (b, c) => new { b, c }),
                      (a, bc) => Tuple.Create(a, bc.b, bc.c));
}
```

As for whether LINQ is suitable for this - having the `InTriples` method generally available means that the rest of the code becomes pretty simple. Using Skip/Zip isn't going to be terribly efficient, but once you've got the code going using that, you can easily rewrite the `InTriples` method to use an iteerator block instead.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative solution with summing into list directly, without creating triples:

```
var bestIndex = someList.Zip(someList.Skip(1), (a, b) => a + b)
                        .Zip(someList.Skip(2), (a, b) => a + b)
                        .Select((v, i) => new
                        {
                           Value = v,
                           Index = i
                        })
                       .OrderByDescending(x => x.Value )
                       .First()
                       .Index;
```

Comment: It doesn't create triples - but it does create value/index doubles. I've often thought that that overload of `Select` is used for that purpose so often that it would be useful to have an IndexedValue struct, and a `WithIndex` method to create a sequence of them. (I can't remember whether I've already got that in MoreLINQ...)

Comment: @JonSkeet, isn't that my solution creates one temporary list, while yours creates two?

Comment: Well neither of them creates a temporary list - they create lazily-evaluated sequences. But yes, mine creates more instances of anonymous types, with the downside of that - but the upside of being more reusable for other operations on those triples.

Answer (score 0):

seems to return first highest sequence

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;



namespace take3highestsum
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //question sequence
        List<int> intlist = new List<int> { 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 2, 1, 3, 7, 1 };


        //display in console stuff not part of answer
        foreach (int a in intlist)
        {
            Console.Write(a + " ");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();


        //begin answer


        //check for legit list since we need at least 3 elements
        if (intlist.Count < 3) { throw new Exception("List must have more than 3 elements"); }

        //stuff we will need
        int lastindx = intlist.Count - 1, baseindex = -1;            

        //begin LINQ
        int[] result = intlist.Select(a =>
        {
            baseindex++;//increment

            //return each sequence of three numbers
            return new int[]{ 
                intlist[baseindex],//always base index
                baseindex + 1 > lastindx ? 0 : intlist[baseindex + 1], //base index + 1 or 0 if out of bounds 
                baseindex + 2 > lastindx ? 0 : intlist[baseindex + 2] };//base index + 2 or 0 if out of bounds 

        }).OrderByDescending(b => b.Sum()).First();
        //end LINQ
        //end answer

         //stuff to display proof
        foreach (int a in result)
        {    
            Console.Write(a);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
 }
}
```